# Compiling signed pdf online

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I need to do some testing and need to compile a document with a PAdES signature field online.

I have tried a few, but most online systems exclude the digsig and eforms packages.

Any suggestions?

Is there a way to add the package?

Comment: Don't these require Acrobat? If so, it seems unlikely that an online service is going to provide it.

Comment: You need to add the empty signature field in pdfLaTeX with eforms or digsig.  You only need Acrobat (or some other package) to insert the final signature.

Comment: If using `SageMath` see (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290013) for how.