# How to create eforms.sty with online Latex?

Tags: packages, online

I am using a online Latex compiler such as [sharelatex.com](http://sharelatex.com) or cloud.sagemath.com

I need to include the package `eforms.sty`.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Sagemath` cloud, upload the required `*.ins` files and create the `.sty` by un-commenting the `\input` commands below:

```
% 2016-01-29 stripped

% The following files were used to create the style sheets
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input eforms.ins
%\input insdljs.ins
%\input taborder.ins


\documentclass{article}
```